# Help identifying piece with slide handles on both ends

Tags: part-identification

I'm trying to build a custom build from YouTube and it contains a piece that I've never seen before. I'm completely stumped. Can anyone identify the brick and part number?

I've attached the image. It's from [this](https://youtu.be/6S0mxqKU0SM?t=137) video @ 2:17

Any ideas??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [battle droid torso](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30375), part 30375.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!